# returning wrong result for previous and current value from same row

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table

```
 CMPI_CODE   CMI_CODE CMN_CDTY_MTRL CMPI_PRICE_TYPE   TRM_CODE ENTRY_DATE   USR_CODE CMPI_PRCINX CMPI_ID_REF CMPI_UPDATE_STS CMPI_EFF_DATE
---------- ---------- ------------- --------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------- ----------- --------------- -------------
       141         57           344 AL                         26-MAY-14           0          88         135 N               14-MAY-14     
       135         57           344 AL                         24-MAY-14           0          91         134 N               14-MAY-25     
       134         57           344 AL                         24-MAY-14           0          90         132 N               14-MAY-01     
       132         57           344 PL                         24-MAY-14           0         100             N               14-MAY-01     
       133         58           345 PL                         24-MAY-14           0          55             N               14-MAY-01
```

I want to get Currnet_Price and Previous Price.. 
My try is this

```
  SELECT 
  NTH_VALUE(CMPI_PRCINX,1) FROM LAST OVER (PARTITION BY CMI_CODE ORDER BY CMPI_CODE  ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS cur,
         NTH_VALUE(CMPI_PRCINX,2) FROM LAST OVER (PARTITION BY CMI_CODE ORDER BY CMPI_CODE  ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS PREVIOUS_PRICE
  FROM CMD_MTRL_PRICE_INF B  
  WHERE CMPI_CODE IN (SELECT MAX(CMPI_CODE) FROM CMD_MTRL_PRICE_INF GROUP BY CMI_CODE) ORDER BY CMPI_CODE
```

output

```
CURRENT_PRICE PREVIOUS_PRICE
------------- --------------
          55                
          88
```

but it should show some thing like this

```
PREVIOUS_PRICE CURRENT_PRICE  
-------------- ------------- 
                          55 
            91            88
```

Need some help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this also

```
 WITH
PRICEINFO AS(
SELECT B.*,
NTH_VALUE(CMPI_PRCINX,2) FROM LAST OVER (PARTITION BY CMI_CODE ORDER BY CMPI_CODE ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS PREVIOUS_PRICE
FROM CMD_MTRL_PRICE_INF B
)
SELECT PREVIOUS_PRICE,CMPI_PRCINX AS CURRENT_PRICE FROM PRICEINFO
WHERE CMPI_CODE IN (SELECT MAX(CMPI_CODE) FROM CMD_MTRL_PRICE_INF GROUP BY CMI_CODE) ORDER BY CMPI_CODE
```

Answer (score 3):

Your WHERE clause is filtering out all rows, except ones with max CMPI_CODE before applying the functions. So your NTH_VALUE function can't pick up the previous value.

You can simplify it.

- NTH_VALUE(CMPI_PRCINX,1) is redundant.
- NTH_VALUE(CMPI_PRCINX,2) can be replaced with LAG.
- You can use ROW_NUMBER to get the max CMPI_CODE.
- Once you calculate the previous CMPI_PRCINX, you should filter out the rows.

Query:

```
select cur, prev
from (
        select CMPI_PRCINX cur,
               lag(CMPI_PRCINX) over (partition by CMI_CODE order by CMPI_CODE) prev,
               row_number() over (partition by CMI_CODE order by CMPI_CODE desc) r
        from CMD_MTRL_PRICE_INF
    )
where r = 1;
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/65717c/7).